# Sort based on alignment

Tags: excel

I have an interesting predicament. I have a column of values and each alignment has a specific meaning (left is new parts, right is core parts, center is obsolete). I want to get rid of all center-aligned values because they're irrelevant in this sheet. (I copied this list from another sheet that needed obsolete parts)

Is there a way to filter/sort based on alignment? I'm only finding based on cell/font color. The problem seems too miniscule to use vba for this specific sheet.

Comment: I'm afraid you may be stuck doing VBA for this one. It's a shame someone thought it was clever to assign deeper meaning to an entry based upon its text alignment. Especially since it visually depends upon the width of the column.

Comment: I think that someone was me actually lol. At least using the center alignment to signify obsolescence. The core parts have a C at the beginning of the number to signify it as such so filtering based on that would be simple enough. I guess I'll just trawl through 900 lines of data and hope this issue doesn't come up again. :D

Comment: @pnuts that deserves to be an answer

Comment: @pnuts I just thought it was an interesting question.  (If the OP didn't know about `=Cell(` then it would be very hard to find)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a helper column with something like, copied down to suit:

```
=CELL("prefix",A1)
```

you would have something to filter on (say select `^` only) and then be able to delete the respective rows.

[From the Help page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf?NS=EXCEL&Version=16&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZXL160&HelpId=xlmain11.chm60173&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

> Prefix:
>   Text value corresponding to the "label prefix" of the cell. Returns single quotation mark (`'`) if the cell contains left-aligned text, double quotation mark (`"`) if the cell contains right-aligned text, caret (`^`) if the cell contains centered text, backslash (`\`) if the cell contains fill-aligned text, and empty text (`""`) if the cell contains anything else.

Comment: Holy cow! Yeah, I had no idea about the cell function. Like, I've seen it before but I never really used it.

Comment: Agreed. But your method allowed me to cut out almost 100 lines in a few minutes. It would have taken longer to write the VBA. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In VBA, you would check the cells HorizontalAlignment, such as:

> cells(1,1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

This would give you a `True`/`False` condition based on the horizontal alignment of A1.

The other conditions you could check for would be `xlDistributed`, `xlJustify`, `xlLeft`, or `xlRight`.

Comment: I appreciate the vba answer. I knew it'd be possible, I just didn't want to open that can of worms on this just yet. Definitely keeping this in my back pocket until I need to use it.

Comment: If you don't want to write a complete sub, you could write it as a simple function, or UDF, that could be called by your formulas.